# Resource images not working c++

Tags: c++, winapi, resources

**SOLVED:** The problem was with ::CreateCompatibleBitmap ( hdc, 26, 26  ); I was creating a 26x26 bitmap where as the actual bitmap was 166x166, since the background color of the window and the bitmap was same so it wasn't visible when ::BitBlt ed. Such a stupid mistake.

---

This is a strange problem, few resource bmp images are not showing up when I ::BitBlt them, if I replace the images in question with a different bmp file(no change in the code) then it works. There are more bmp files in resource and they are working.
What could be the problem with the BMPs ?
I have checked with resource hacker and images are there in the executable.

Following is what I am doing in code.

Resource.rc

```
IDB_ANIMMAIN_1                      BITMAP  DISCARDABLE "E:\\image\\AnimMain\\AnimMain_1.bmp"
IDB_ANIMMAIN_2                      BITMAP  DISCARDABLE "E:\\image\\AnimMain\\AnimMain_2.bmp"
IDB_ANIMMAIN_3                      BITMAP  DISCARDABLE "E:\\image\\AnimMain\\AnimMain_3.bmp"
IDB_ANIMMAIN_4                      BITMAP  DISCARDABLE "E:\\image\\AnimMain\\AnimMain_4.bmp"
IDB_ANIMMAIN_5                      BITMAP  DISCARDABLE "E:\\image\\AnimMain\\AnimMain_5.bmp"
IDB_ANIMMAIN_6                      BITMAP  DISCARDABLE "E:\\image\\AnimMain\\AnimMain_6.bmp"
IDB_ANIMMAIN_7                      BITMAP  DISCARDABLE "E:\\image\\AnimMain\\AnimMain_7.bmp"
IDB_ANIMMAIN_8                      BITMAP  DISCARDABLE "E:\\image\\AnimMain\\AnimMain_8.bmp"
IDB_ANIMMAIN_9                      BITMAP  DISCARDABLE "E:\\image\\AnimMain\\AnimMain_9.bmp"
IDB_ANIMMAIN_10                     BITMAP  DISCARDABLE "E:\\image\\AnimMain\\AnimMain_10.bmp"
IDB_ANIMMAIN_11                     BITMAP  DISCARDABLE "E:\\image\\AnimMain\\AnimMain_11.bmp"
IDB_ANIMMAIN_12                     BITMAP  DISCARDABLE "E:\\image\\AnimMain\\AnimMain_12.bmp"
```

Resource.h

```
#define   IDB_ANIMMAIN_1                                    501
#define   IDB_ANIMMAIN_2                                    502
#define   IDB_ANIMMAIN_3                                    503
#define   IDB_ANIMMAIN_4                                    504
#define   IDB_ANIMMAIN_5                                    505
#define   IDB_ANIMMAIN_6                                    506
#define   IDB_ANIMMAIN_7                                    507
#define   IDB_ANIMMAIN_8                                    508
#define   IDB_ANIMMAIN_9                                    509
#define   IDB_ANIMMAIN_10                               510
#define   IDB_ANIMMAIN_11                               511
#define   IDB_ANIMMAIN_12                               512
```

main.cpp

```
std::vector < HBITMAP > bitmaps;

bitmaps.push_back (   ::LoadBitmap (  hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE ( IDB_ANIMMAIN_1 )  )   );

bitmaps.push_back (   ::LoadBitmap (  hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE ( IDB_ANIMMAIN_2 )  )   );

bitmaps.push_back (   ::LoadBitmap (  hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE ( IDB_ANIMMAIN_3 )  )   );

bitmaps.push_back (   ::LoadBitmap (  hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE ( IDB_ANIMMAIN_4 )  )   );

bitmaps.push_back (   ::LoadBitmap (  hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE ( IDB_ANIMMAIN_5 )  )   );

bitmaps.push_back (   ::LoadBitmap (  hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE ( IDB_ANIMMAIN_6 )  )   );

bitmaps.push_back (   ::LoadBitmap (  hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE ( IDB_ANIMMAIN_7 )  )   );

bitmaps.push_back (   ::LoadBitmap (  hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE ( IDB_ANIMMAIN_8 )  )   );

bitmaps.push_back (   ::LoadBitmap (  hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE ( IDB_ANIMMAIN_9 )  )   );

bitmaps.push_back (   ::LoadBitmap (  hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE ( IDB_ANIMMAIN_10 )  )   );

bitmaps.push_back (   ::LoadBitmap (  hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE ( IDB_ANIMMAIN_11 )  )   );

bitmaps.push_back (   ::LoadBitmap (  hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE ( IDB_ANIMMAIN_12 )  )   );
```

update:

```
HDC hdc = ::GetDC ( hwnd );

int i = 0;


while ( running )
{


    hbitmap = bitmaps [ i ];

    ::Sleep ( 200 );        paint ( hdc );


    i++;


    if (  i >= bitmaps.size (  )  )     i = 0;



}


::ReleaseDC ( hwnd, hdc );



return true;
```

Following is how I am doing the paint, the paint function is called from a loop that does the animation(for which the images are used), the this->hbitmap is updated in the loop.
If I change the IDB_ANIMMAIN_x in the ::LoadBitmap call to another resource identifier then it works, so I am sure the loop and onpaint(); are working.

onpaint:

```
HDC dcSkin = ::CreateCompatibleDC ( hdc );

HDC hMemDc = ::CreateCompatibleDC ( hdc );


HBITMAP hmemBmp = ::CreateCompatibleBitmap ( hdc, 26, 26  );


HBITMAP hOldMemBmp = (HBITMAP) ::SelectObject ( hMemDc, hmemBmp );


HBITMAP hOldSkinBmp = (HBITMAP) ::SelectObject ( dcSkin, this->hbitmap );


        //::MessageBox ( 0, "second", "jAnimationBig::paint", 0 );
        ::BitBlt ( hMemDc, 0, 0, width, height, dcSkin, 0, 0, SRCCOPY );

        ::BitBlt ( hdc, 0, 0, width, height, hMemDc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY );



::SelectObject ( hMemDc, hOldMemBmp );
::SelectObject ( dcSkin, hOldSkinBmp );


::DeleteObject ( hOldSkinBmp );
::DeleteObject ( hOldMemBmp );
::DeleteObject(  hmemBmp );
::DeleteDC ( hMemDc );
::DeleteDC ( dcSkin );
```

Comment: Check if the bitmaps have strange encoding - 16-bit, monochrome, or indexed, that is incompatible with your HDC. Or try to convert them to 24-bit colors with an image editor. Also, post the code that of the actual BitBlt and the creation of the HDC.

Comment: @sashoalm I have updated the code above. And I do not know how to check the bitmaps :(

Comment: Check them with an image editor. Or Google about it, or something. Read this - http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/bitmaps/

Comment: @sashoalm I checked with photoshop, they are RGB(not indexed) and 8bits/channel(so it makes them 24bits). :?

Comment: Did you check in the debugger if your bitmaps actually loaded correctly?

Comment: One thing I remember about bitmaps is that a lot of them are compressed, check that this isnt the case, best thing to do is run the whole set through something like gimp for example and ensure origin is in the same corner and that they all have the same properties set as one of the images which works, then save them (you could probably script this in a decent package, or if you dont have that many images do a quick once through manually).  Specifics to look out for are colour depth, RLE being on or off and origin corner.

Comment: You should put your solution as an answer to the question, rather than edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**: The problem was with **::CreateCompatibleBitmap ( hdc, 26, 26 );** I was creating a **26x26** bitmap where as the actual bitmap was **166x166**, since the background color of the window and the bitmap was same so it wasn't visible when **::BitBlt ed**. Such a stupid mistake.